# Approximately when will the hurricane make landfall?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Approximately when will the hurricane make landfall?

Time (hours): 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Distance (miles): 704, 684, 663.7, 644.2, 624.4

Function rule: f(x)=$0.1833x^{3}-0.6999x^{2}-19.4834x+704$

I do not understand what the question is asking me to do. I have no idea how to solve this question. Am I supposed to equal my equation to zero and solve? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: They want to find $x$ when $f(x)=0$

Comment: @Andrei thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the position of the storm as a function of time. The hurricane was at zero distance in the past ($-16.5$ hours).

[image: Graph]

Comment: thank you this was very helpful.